# Have GNU Indent Add New Braces After If Statement

Tags: c, gnu-indent

I have a project where we're investigating adding a requirement for if conditionals to include braces (the reason is unimportant and off topic). For example:

```c
if (foo)
  return bar;
else
  return baz;
```

Becomes:

```c
if (foo) {
  return bar;
} else {
  return baz;
}
```

We already use GNU indent to do all sorts of code style checking so ideally we'd be able to force this requirement using GNU indent as we already do with our other style requirements. We can put all that in a Git pre-commit hook and no one has to worry about messing things up.

I can't seem to find a way to force these new braces to actually show up though. It looks like GNU indent will only check that they're in the right spot if they're already there. **Is there some way to require these braces to actually be present too?**

Comment: Formatting programs like this usually don't change the code, they just rearrange it.

Comment: thats just like `alias`...

Comment: It's also a matter of style whether you omit the unnecessary `else`.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, you right, but only when using `return`.

Comment: @BladeMight or `break`, `continue` or the hateful `goto`.

Comment: @WeatherVane hateful indeed.... :)

Comment: *Is there some way to require these braces to actually be present too?* - we use code review for that :)

Comment: I believe [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) provides options like `mod_full_brace_if = ignore   # ignore/add/remove/force` with the explanation `# Add or remove braces on single-line 'if' statement. Will not remove the braces if they contain an 'else'.`.  And a good size collection of related options.

Answer (score 1):

No. There's a reason it's called `indent`. It only indents code.

I think `clang-format` might have this capability but I'd have to review the configuration to make sure.

My personal preference would be to just add them manually and turn on compiler warnings if not having them is causing issues with your code.